# samples about GTMMIMEDocument

Tags: ios, http, post

I am using GTMFetcher lib（http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/） on iOS.But I can't find any samples about GTMMIMEDocument on internet.Where I can find them? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample on the gtm-http-fetcher project wiki [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/MultipartPost).